# How similar are two words?

Tags: c++, similarity

I would like to measure the similarity between two words. The similarity will be a function written in c++ which return a float between 0 and 1. If the two words a very similar, then that float will be near 1 and if they are very differents, then it will be something near 0. For instance, "Analyse" and "Analise" might return 0.95 and "Substracting" and "describe" might return something near 0. How can I do that in c++.

Attempt:

```
float similarity(const std::string& word1, const std::string& word2) const{
    const std::size_t len1 = word1.size();
    const std::size_t len2 = word2.size();
    float score = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i<std::min(len1,len2);i++){
        score += (float)(word1[i]==word2[i])/len1;
    }
    return score;
}
```

Is it fine? Am I able to do a better job? I don't need machine learning here. This is just for testing purposes, but I can't make it too bad as well. The above attempt is ok, but it is not enough.

Comment: You have to be much more precise with your definition of "similarity". The examples you've given don't make it clear at all.

Comment: Seems like a problem for an AI to solve.

Comment: See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus-program-to-implement-levenshtein-distance-computing-algorithm#:~:text=The%20Levenshtein%20distance%20between%20two,substitution%20of%20a%20single%20character.&text=Here%20is%20a%20C%2B%2B%20Program%20to%20implement%20Levenshtein%20Distance%20computing%20algorithm.

Comment: @cigien Let me modify my question to make it a bit more clear.

Comment: See [Edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) in Wikipedia, there are several metrics on words described there..

Comment: Implementing a good similarity function is clearly not a simple problem. If you are asking about algorithm options, there are some answers here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12575/similarity-between-two-words

Comment: This question is now too broad. You're asking for *some* similarity metric and have not stated clearly what the requirements are. There are many different options, and the question is not really answerable till you narrow the requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) and [Levenshtein Distance Implementation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance)

You can use the result of the above mentioned algorithm to achieve what you need

Later edit:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

unsigned int edit_distance(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2) {
    const std::size_t len1 = s1.size(), len2 = s2.size();
    std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>> d(len1 + 1, std::vector<unsigned int>(len2 + 1));

    d[0][0] = 0;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= len1; ++i) d[i][0] = i;
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= len2; ++i) d[0][i] = i;

    for(unsigned int i = 1; i <= len1; ++i)
        for(unsigned int j = 1; j <= len2; ++j)
                      d[i][j] = std::min(std::min(d[i - 1][j] + 1, d[i][j - 1] + 1),
                                         d[i - 1][j - 1] + (s1[i - 1] == s2[j - 1] ? 0 : 1));
    return d[len1][len2];
}

float similarity(const std::string& s1, const std::string& s2) {
    return 1 - 1.0 * edit_distance(s1, s2) / std::max(s1.size(), s2.size());
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> words = {
        { "Julius", "Iulius" },
        { "Frank", "Blank" },
        { "George", "Dog" },
        { "Cat", "Elephant" },
        { "Cucumber", "Tomato" }
    };
    for (const auto& word_pair : words) {
        std::cout << "Similarity between [" << word_pair.first << "] & ["
        << word_pair.second << "]: " << similarity(word_pair.first, word_pair.second)
        << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and the output:

```
Similarity between [Julius] & [Iulius]: 0.833333
Similarity between [Frank] & [Blank]: 0.6
Similarity between [George] & [Dog]: 0.333333
Similarity between [Cat] & [Elephant]: 0.25
Similarity between [Cucumber] & [Tomato]: 0.125
```

Comment: Considering the function has to return a float between 0 and 1, are you up to show me what this implementation will look like here? It seems to return a hint

Comment: A number between 0 and 1 is called a proper fraction (fractions where the numerator is smaller than the denominator). You can take the algo's result and divide it by the length of the longest string, thus giving you a number between 0 and 1. The algo gives you at most the length of the longer string, so you won't exceed 1. As an example, let's say you have the result of the algo 7 for two 10 letters words. 7/10 = 0.7 (but you want it the other way, so you can substract 1 from this) => 1 - 7/10 = 0.3, which basically tells you that the words are pretty far apart.

Comment: If you can do it, I will accept your answer

Comment: @Robert see the edited answer and upvote if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best and only way to make this is machine learning. If you want to do this with c++ it is going to be really hard. I would recommend python and TensorFlow for example.

Comment: There are many libraries out there that do a great job in calculating the similarity between words without the need of using machine learning. Throwing machine learning on every problem is a trendy practice, but that does not mean that this is a good idea. And creating a good training set isn’t an easy task.